# How should I proceed for develop mobile games?

Tags: javascript

I've been learning javascript for 4 days and I know the basics.
How should I proceed for develop mobile games?

Comment: This is too generic of a question and not technically accurate for someone to answer. Please take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A collection of good links for gaming with javascript:
https://github.com/DaRaFF/jsgamewiki